# Verify captcha use svg-captcha npm

Tags: node.js, svg, captcha

I am using svg-captcha library [(link npm)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-captcha), however I can't find a way to validate captcha sent from user to server.

Now I can use it to generate captcha and return the client.
Here is my code:

```
app.get('/captcha', function (req, res) {
    var captcha = svgCaptcha.create();
    req.session.captcha = captcha.text;
    
    res.type('svg');
    res.status(200).send(captcha.data);
});
```

I use node.js

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm late here but you can create a unique id for the captcha, then save that uid and captcha text on your server, and send the captcha uid with captcha data on response. So from there users can send request including the captcha text solved from client and the captcha uid in their requests. Then you can just compare it with the stored captcha.
Here is what users receive when they get the captcha:

```
{
    "key": "some kind of uid",
    "content": "<svg your catpcha data></svg>"
}
```

And here is what they send back:

```
{
    "ckey": "the captcha uid they received",
    "cvalue": "value of the captcha they solve",
    "some_params": "some values"
}
```